# Remote desktop connection logs in after 2 minutes

Tags: remote-desktop, login

We have a set of Windows 10 computers where we connect remotely via remote desktop connection. We have a single user that we use to log in and it's configured as administrator on these machines.

The problem we are facing on some of them is that each time we want to log in we need to wait for over 2 minutes. After the user pass prompt we get to this Welcome screen and nothing happens until those >2 minutes have passed. Afterwards, we get to the desktop and everything is fine.

On the other computers the log in process is almost immediate, there's no waiting time. We're unsure what causes this.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this behaviour before? What might it be related to?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this.  My windows 10 does this constantly.  I have to wait about 10mins on mine.  I have tried many remedies but nothing has worked.  I have determined that this is profile based.  So a workaround/solution is

- Create a  new admin profile
- Test with this
- If it works

  - then delete the old profile
  - create a new profile of the old name